# JQuery UI Autocomplete Send Extra Term By JSON

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I took most of this code from jQuery UI documentation.
I want to add to the request variables such that the `<input>` id is also sent.

Input looks like this:

```
<input size="50" class="attr_values" name="msrp" id="msrp" />
```

Now here's the jquery. Inside of .autocomplete source $.getJSON I try to use "this.id" and it doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // 2 string parsing functions
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }


    $( '.attr_values' )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( 'keydown', function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( 'autocomplete' ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( 'controllers/core_data/ajax/core_data.php', {
                    'attr_name' : this.id, // THIS DOESN'T WORK
                    'term': extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
                // var attr_name = this.id;
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( '' );
                this.value = terms.join( ', ' );
                return false;
            }
        });

 });
```

Also note that I have applied this to the ".attr_values" class rather than to one particular id like the examples show. I have a whole bunch of fields, each with a different id. That's why I need to send the id  AND term to the php script. So that it knows which table to look the term up in.

Comment: sorry I had the wrong title at the top for a second. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` doesn't refer to the original collection anymore inside the `getJSON` callback. Try drilling upward to get to the original element:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.getJSON( 'controllers/core_data/ajax/core_data.php', {
        'attr_name' : this.element[0].id,
        'term': extractLast( request.term )
    }, response );
},
```

The context `this` here refers to the `autocomplete` object that you are evaluating the `source` function for. We can use the `element` property to get the corresponding jQuery collection, and then find the id from that.

Comment: Looks cool, but "this.id" still isn't working. In fact, now it seems like no data is being sent to "core_data.php" at all.

Comment: @ButtleButkus I've made some changes. Try it now.

Comment: THank you. It works nearly brilliantly. The required data is finally getting through to the php script. The only question I have left is why the Google Chrome debugger is pausing on the closing bracket of the "source" section. Any idea?

Comment: Apparently I did do that. Thanks! I'm going to have another question about this in a minute by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving this..

```
$(this).attr('id');
```